# XML declaration tag in WCF RESTful service

Tags: xml, wcf, xsd

Is it correct to include XML declaration tag like this `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>` into WCF RESTful service response? 
A service response is described by the XSD below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="root">
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Also is we need mandatory set the declaration tag in cause if encoding changed to UTF-16?

Answer (score 0):

An XML Declaration defines the document as XML, as opposed to plain text that happens to have a lot of angle brackets in. So technically, yes you should include it with the XML document to ensure that services will correctly understand it as XML.

However, in a lot of cases XML parsers will attempt to correctly parse a chunk of plain text as XML, if it is well-formed, even if no XML declaration is included.

As per the second part of your question, the declaration becomes neccessary when you start wanting to change the encoding of the document. So you will save yourself a lot of hassle later on by including the declaration if other systems start having to consume the data your are producing.